# graph_from_dot_data doesn't provide write_png module

Tags: graphviz, decision-tree, pydotplus

I have a problem with write_png module of pydotplus.grapg_from_dot_data. Actually, It doesn't even appear as the modules of graph_from_dot_data.
This is my code:

```
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(X,y)
data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree , out_file=None , feature_names= features)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(data).write_png('mydecisiontree.png')
```

This is the error raised:

```
pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem too,
I installed GraphViz from [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) and it solved.
be sure to put GraphViz in the environment path

Comment: Thanks. I searched a lot and finally solved the problem using GraphViz :)